# NameError: uninitialized constant GemName::Rails::Railtie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railtie

I'm creating a gem to encapslate a chunk of functionality from an application. Them gem essentially runs a rake task, but when I run the task with `bundle exec rake:assets:precompile`, I get the following error

```
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'gem-name'.
/Users/tonyedwardspz/myprojects/westcornwallevents/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tonyedwardspz/myprojects/westcornwallevents/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/Users/tonyedwardspz/myprojects/westcornwallevents/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
NameError: uninitialized constant GemName::Rails::Railtie
/Users/tonyedwardspz/myprojects/westcornwallevents/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tonyedwardspz/myprojects/westcornwallevents/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/Users/tonyedwardspz/myprojects/westcornwallevents/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

The code for the module related to railtie is:

```
require 'rails'

module GemName
  module Rails
    class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
      railtie_name :gem_name

      rake_tasks do
        load "tasks/gem_name.rake"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the syntax of the class definition. Updating the code as following will allow the rake task to run.

```
class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
```

to

```
class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie
```